# How to combine separate front end (react.js - cra) and back end (asp.net core) applications into a single application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

We currently have a reactjs front end app that runs on its own and is deployed to an azure app service on one sub domain, and a back end app, the api, an asp.net core app that is deployed to another app service on its own subdomain.  Both have authentication managed by a third app, that uses identity server to authenticate requests to either the front or backend, that also is its own app service in azure.  We'd like to combine the front-end and back-end.  Is it possible for them to run together if we create a wwwroot folder in the api project and move the react app into there, and then modify the api project to serve static files? How does that impact the auth server usage in the mix?  I assume that means we'd need to move to take advantage of duende bff then.  Is this common?  We'd like to do this in an effort to stop jwt token usage, because having the front end and back end in the same project/app would mean they are the same domain and we could authenticate with the auth server and get a samesite browser cookie for auth instead of the front end directly going to the auth server to get a token and store it in browser storage.

Comment: That sounds like a **really** complicated way to get them on the same domain. Also a bad idea. Just use a reverse proxy to serve both apps on different paths on the same domain.

Comment: My recommendation is to always put IdentityServer on its own domain/Service, will be horrible complicated to debug otherwise.

Comment: I would keep the identity server as a separate project/domain app, but we'd like to combine the react front end and api apps into a single app that can take advantage of duende bff, and remove the token management from the react app in lieu of an auth cookie...as it is inherently a problem storing an auth token in a browser, and even though many spas, like we have, operate on their own domain/app and manage token storage this way as a result, it is increasingly not recommended (see Dominick Baier/Brock Allen of Duende server on this).

Comment: The thing is that we are not aware of your front-end and back-end projects. There is no straightforward way available to do it that could work with any project. You need to make tests at each step to see whether combining the two projects going well or not. All we could suggest is that you could try to refer to the React Asp.Net Core template and combine your projects like that. You could try to keep the structure similar to the template. While combining it, if you face any issues then you could ask that specific question here.

Comment: If I were to use a proxy like YARP, how would I go about it - do I have to have a fourth, separate project that runs this by itself (and host it in another azure app service), or can I build it into the current API project?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Visual Studio already has a project template that uses ReactJS(for front-end) and C#.Net Core(for back-end).

[image]

You should have used this template while making this project solution in the first place.

As your ReactJS and .Net Core projects already exist, it will be difficult to combine them.

I am not sure whether it will work successfully but while checking the project structure. I noticed that the React app was placed in the Client App folder in the .Net Core project.

[image]

If it doesn't work then you could use the template from the Visual Studio project and try to move your code into that project.

Below are some helpful references:

1. [Use React with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)
2. [Integrate Create React app with .NET Core 5](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/integrate-create-react-app-with-net-core-5/)
3. [Single project that contain React plus ASP.NET Core MVC Application](https://www.srinadimpalli.com/2019/12/single-project-that-contain-react-plus-asp-net-core-mvc-application/)